# The server principal "sa" is not able to access the database "model" under the current security context

Tags: sql-server, execute-as

I created a stored procedure which performs a series of operations that require special permissions, e.g. create database, restore database, etc. I create this stored procedure with

```
execute as self
```

...so that it runs as SA. This is because I want to give a SQL user without any permissions the ability to run only these commands which I have defined.

But when I run this stored proc, I get

```
The server principal "sa" is not able to access the database "model" under the current security context.
```

How come SA can't access the model database? I actually ran the code in the stored proc on its own, under SA, and it ran fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read [Extending Database Impersonation by Using EXECUTE AS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188304%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) before you continue.

> when impersonating a principal by using the EXECUTE AS USER statement,
>   or within a database-scoped module by using the EXECUTE AS clause, the
>   scope of impersonation is restricted to the database by default. This
>   means that references to objects outside the scope of the database
>   will return an error.

You need to use [module signing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345102%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). [Here](http://rusanu.com/2006/03/01/signing-an-activated-procedure/) is an example.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody else coming here looking for this info, here is sample code that demonstrates exactly what OP (and I) wanted (based on excellent info from Remus above):

```
    -- how to sign a stored procedure so it can access other Databases on same server
    -- adapted from this very helpful article 
    -- http://rusanu.com/2006/03/01/signing-an-activated-procedure/

    USE [master]
    GO
    CREATE DATABASE TempDB1
    CREATE DATABASE OtherDB2
    GO
    USE TempDB1
    GO
    -- create a user for TempDB1
    CREATE USER [foo] WITHOUT LOGIN
    GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE TempDB1_SP 
    AS 
    BEGIN 
        CREATE TABLE OtherDB2.dbo.TestTable (ID int NULL)
        IF @@ERROR=0 PRINT 'Successfully created table.' 
    END
    GO

    GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.TempDB1_SP TO [foo]
    GO

    EXECUTE AS User='foo'
        PRINT 'Try to run an SP that accesses another database:'
        EXECUTE dbo.TempDB1_SP
        GO
    REVERT

    -- Output: Msg 916, Level 14, State 1, Procedure TempDB1_SP, Line 5
    --   [Batch Start Line 14]
    -- The server principal "..." is not able to access the database 
    --    "OtherDB2" under the current security context.

    PRINT ''
    PRINT 'Fix: Try again with signed SP...'

    -- Create cert with private key to sign the SP with. 
    -- Password not important, will drop private key

    USE TempDB1
    GO
    -- create a self-signed cert
    CREATE CERTIFICATE [DB_Cert] 
        ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'Password1' 
        WITH SUBJECT = 'Signing for cross-DB SPs';
    -- Sign the procedure with the certificate’s private key
    ADD SIGNATURE TO OBJECT::[TempDB1_SP] 
        BY CERTIFICATE [DB_Cert] 
        WITH PASSWORD = 'Password1'
    -- Drop the private key. This way it cannot be used again to sign other procedures.
    ALTER CERTIFICATE [DB_Cert] REMOVE PRIVATE KEY
    -- Copy the public key part of the cert to [master] database 
    -- backup to a file and create cert from file in [master]
    BACKUP CERTIFICATE [DB_Cert] TO FILE = 'C:\Users\Public\DBCert.cer'

    USE [OtherDB2] -- or use [master] = all DBs on server accessible
    GO
    CREATE CERTIFICATE [DB_Cert] FROM FILE = 'C:\Users\Public\DBCert.cer';
    -- the 'certificate user' carries the permissions that are automatically granted 
    -- when the signed SP accesses other Databases
    CREATE USER [DB_CertUser] FROM CERTIFICATE [DB_Cert]
    GRANT CREATE TABLE TO [DB_CertUser] -- or whatever other permissions are needed
    GO

    USE TempDB1
    EXECUTE dbo.TempDB1_SP
    GO
    -- output: 'Successfully created table.'
    -- clean up: everything except the cert file, have to delete that yourself sorry
    USE [master]
    GO
    DROP DATABASE TempDB1
    DROP DATABASE OtherDB2
    GO
```